# Unity Container and Support for dotnet Core / netstandard

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-core

So MS dropped (free sourced) Unity. [Future of Unity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/)
The github repository appears inactive [Unity on GitHub](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity)

Anybody know what is going on with Unity ?
Is there a IOC Dependency Injection tool for dotNet Core,
if Unity is a dead end under dotnet core?

EDIT: Still waiting on news about Unity.
**Alternatives for those searching**: [StructureMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/structuremap/)  ,  [AutoFac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/)
or our selection , [SimpleInjector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/4.0.0-beta1)  It very active on GitHub. There are many downloads daily already ~1Million from Nuget alone. And its fast, very well documented, a nice API with good extensibility.  **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** would have been the next choice. We dont have ASP.NET project, If you do then definitely look at MS DI. You can use MS DI in DotNet Core too,
I like [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.org) more. The docu is good, with over 500 downloads a day and more than 1 million in total, Simpleinjector has gone past critical mass.

**EDIT2:** Unity might just do a phoenix for .netcore. It is still kicking.
[See Unity for .netStandard discussion](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues/198) on github.  Although there isnt a great deal of activity yet. There is at least some support to get it working on Core. The question is will it be too little too late?
Late migrators may still benefit. For now (2018) it still looks like alternatives are requried.
SimpleInjector is on making solid progress as a legitimate replacement.
[See SimpleInjector Nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/).
Nearly 3 million downloads and >1k per day. As of June 2018.

Comment: nice tutorial about DI in net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection . you don't need unity anymore.

Comment: Thx Matthias. ASP.Net or for dotnet core Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is Ok, but not like StructureMap AutoFac or Unity.  I have been using Unity in DotNet Frameworks for years. I went to use in dotnet core and found it wasnt available. Im still curious about Unity in dotnet core, but it looks like i need to choose between Autofac or StructureMap.   The ASP.Net IOC is of consideration in ASP.net mvc projects.  That doesnt apply to me.

Comment: Matthias you should change comment to answer. It is worth at least a tick. Best answer so far.

Comment: Have you tried just referencing the Unity DLL? According to the Portability Analyzer, the Microsoft.Practices.Unity DLL (at least the v2.0.414 version that I'm using) is 100% compatible with .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: For anyone reading this question. there is support for .netcore
https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection

Comment: Just noticing  25K views and closed. Seems a few people were interested in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For net core you can find a nice tutorial about Dependency Injection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection or 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/28/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core/

Imho, implementing and using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is much easier, too. (At least for MVC-Web-Applications) you don't need unity anymore.

Comment: Given microsoft provides automated registration processes for some tools even in non ASP situations andthe pervasiveness of tool make it a good suggestion and common ground for .net core solutions

Comment: there were a lot of lost features in unity. one example is interceptors, don't get with `Microsoft.Extentions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: @ChrisHayes so you are downvoting me for something that microsoft did not implement in their library? how about spending a few seconds with the search-function and you can find alternatives for interceptors, instead of voting my answer as "not useful". Other stackoverflow-users add another answer, writing "in addition to ...s answer, here is how to implement the missing function ...:" - just a hint, how stackoverflow works positive.

Comment: let's assume that I downvoted your answer. your answer does not answer the OP title. and THAT is how stackoverflow works. :(